# Vim syntax colouring for gcov not working as inteded

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm new to Vim, and am a little puzzled.

I'm using `gcov` (through clang), and installed a `.gcov` vim syntax file from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2118) by placing it in my vim `syntax` folder - but the highlighting doesn't appear.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these two lines in your `~/.vimrc` for syntax highlighting to work properly:

```
filetype on
syntax on
```

Because it's generally what people want, you should probably use:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

The first line ensures that Vim recognizes the filetype, loads any filetype-specific options/mappings/autocmds and applies the filetype's built-in indent rules.

The second line activates synatx highlighting.

Comment: does it matter that I don't have a `~/.vimrc`, and rather its in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` ?

Comment: **Never touch `/usr/share/vim`!** Where did you put that `gcov.vim` file?

Comment: Move it to `~/.vim/syntax/gcov.vim` or `~/.vim/after/syntax/gcov.vim`.

Comment: `~/.vim` doesn't exist. Should I create it?

Comment: Yes. `~/.vim` is the directory where *you* put *your* plugins and `~/.vimrc` is the file where *you* put *your* settings. Vim creates neither one nor the other for you so you must create them yourself.